Cannot SSH compute engine VM because "gpasswd: /etc/group.3718: No space left on device"
I can't access SSH from anywhere, not able to auto create ssh user ssh key, so how can I free/cleanup my VM device space?
trying access via serial port output

Boot in rescue mode, mount the root partition, and then delete something to free up space.

Thank you for your answer, got strange result, I was following https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/recover-vm but suddenly old VM able to access after I created new snapshot and while creating new VM from snapshot. its funny!

This answer will not work for Google Cloud VMs. The correct procedure is to resize the boot disk.
